# Seeking US Border Patrol Sectors shapefile

Tags: data-request, geospatial, usa, data.gov

I am trying to find a shapefile containing the boundaries of the different border patrol sectors as shown [here.](https://www.migrationpolicy.org/sites/default/files/source_charts/spot-oct11-cbp-sectors.cfm)

I have searched the US BP website and other sources/databases extensively. There are plenty of maps depiciting their border patrol sectors online (journalist sites even use them for mapping), so it's gotta be somewhere. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: can you provide an example of them in use on a journalist site?

Comment: Number 6 here: https://www.vox.com/2016/8/31/12726292/immigration-speech-amnesty-deportation-border-meaning

Comment: And here as well: https://tucson.com/special-section/beyond-the-wall/why-we-don-t-need-trump-s-great-great-wall/article_f87fd116-399c-11e6-ad53-ab5ac295e9b0.html